# WordPress doesn't activate or deactivate plugins

Tags: wordpress

for some reason my WordPress website isn't able to activate or deactivate plugins. 
On clicking the activate/deactivate option it will output the plugin activated/deactivated text but it never actually changes anything. There is no error message or so being displayed.

The WordPress installation is fully updated and I have no idea what is causing this.

Comment: Go to your plugins folder. Manually cut and paste all the plugins outside and start testing by putting them one by one and see if the problem reappears.

Comment: Maybe you have a JavaScript error in the backend? Open your developer console on the Plugin activation / deactivation page and check for errors.

Comment: Tried disabling plugins and there doesn't seem to be an error in the JS. However I also can't seem to change my user profile on the site. Perhaps something is blocking Wordpress from updating the files? I can however download a new plugin, just the activation part is where the issues start...

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: This smells to me like a file-permissions problem. Read your hosting  provider FAQs or maybe ask them for help. And always hit shift-refresh after making changes to your site to force your browser to reload everything.

Answer (score 0):

Please I will advise you to go to your phpmyadmin and if you don't know which table is faulty. tick all tables and repair them.
after doing this if you try reactivating and it did not work. Log on to your WordPress with another browser, and redo the reactivation process. works like magic

Comment: Went from Chrome to FF, completely different look once I logged in. So hopping browsers helped me here. Also, a hard refresh in Chrome was a winner too.