# Wordpress plugins won't deactivate?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I haven't been able to deactivate any plugin for 3 days.

When trying to deactivate a plugin, Wordpress shows me the classic success message, but the plugin stays activated.

I also have troubles when trying to update widget areas. The widgets in the footer area all disappeared Friday in the late afternoon.

And I can't update plugins options either. For example, I can't update the text displayed by a popup plugin. I can't change cache settings in WP Rocket either.

I tried manually emptying WP Rocket cache by deleting the files contained in  /www/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/www.begoodinbreizh.fr but this doesn't solve the issue.

My database isn't full.

I searched the internet over and over but couldn't find any solution to my problem.

Someone seem to have had the same problem as I have here : 
[Wordpress doesn't activate or deactivate plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851146/wordpress-doesnt-activate-or-deactivate-plugins)

but no solution was raised.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Boris

---

PHP version : 5.6
Theme : [Optima](http://wordpress.vinagecko.net/d/t/optima/)
Web hosting service : OVH

Plugins installed :
* AJAX AutoSuggest
* Boxtal (EnvoiMoinsCher)
* Contact Form 7
* Cookie Notice
* Custom Menu Class
* Easy Facebook Likebox
* Image Widget
* Insert headers and footers
* Loco Translate
* MailPoet 2
* Mega Main Menu
* P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)
* Pixel Caffeine
* Popup Maker
* Product Catalogue Feed by PixelYourSite
* Projects (WooThemes)
* Really Simple SSL
* Redirection
* Redux Framework
* Regenerate Thumbnails
* SEO Ultimate
* Shortcode Ultimate
* Slider Revolution
* Sucuri Security – Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening
* Testimonials (WooThemes)
* Theme Authenticity Checker (TAC)
* TinyMCE Advanced
* UpdraftPlus – Sauvegarde/Restauration
* VG PostCarousel
* VG WooCarousel
* VinaGecko Helper
* Visual Composer
* wBounce
* Widget CSS Classes
* Widget Importer & Exporter
* WooCommerce
* WooCommerce PayPlug
* WooCommerce Promotion Manager
* WordPress Importer
* WP Maintenance
* WP Rocket
* WPBakery Visual Composer 5.2.1
* WPBakery Visual Composer 5.1.1
* YITH WooCommerce Ajax Search
* YITH WooCommerce Badge Management
* YITH WooCommerce Compare

Comment: Don't put solved in the title, just accept an answer.

Comment: @csm_dev > Thanks ! New to stackoverflow, I did not see that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect you in your database, go the table wp_options, find the corresponding plugin field and erase all the value (not the complete line)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. We might be onto something because I can't modify the value in the current snapshot of the DB. When I click Edit, I am being redirected to the Insert page. And when I try using the following query : UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value`= '' WHERE `option_id`=32; MySQL answers "0 line affected". Whereas when I use the 7 days old snapshot of the DB, the Edit button works fine.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-deactivate-all-plugins-when-not-able-to-access-wp-admin/

Comment: SOLVED ! After analysing the wp_options table, I found that it was corrupted so I repaired it. And then, I don't know if it was necessary but I cleared the active_plugins field. Thanks a lot for your help Paul ! Boris

Comment: No problem ;-) Don't forget to validate the answer

Comment: FWIW, clearing the active_plugins field under the wp_options did the trick for me, thanks for posting! 

Answer (score 0):

Also there is something I noticed. If you repair your database table (either wp_options or wp_config) and it is not fixed, try login in with a different browser and try reactivating your plugin again